# PyGTK StatusIcon with transparency

Tags: python, pygtk, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to create a PyGTK [StatusIcon](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkstatusicon.html) with transparent background. I need to draw the contents of the StatusIcon at runtime.

StatusIcon wants a [Pixbuf](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixbuf.html) object (which can have transparency). No problem with that:

```
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, True, 8, width, height)
pixbuf.fill(0xffffffff)
```

The problem is, I can't draw to Pixbuf objects. My current approach is to draw to a [Pixmap](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkpixmap.html) and then convert it to a Pixbuf, but unfortunately Pixmaps can't have transparency.

How do I get a Pixbuf with transparent background that I can draw at runtime?

Greets,
Philip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add transparency to Pixbuf objects with the add_alpha() method. The following line will set zero opacity for the color #ffffff:

```
pixbuf = pixbuf.add_alpha(True, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
```

Too easy...  :-|